# What are the factor that can influence makespan of jobs execution?

Tags: performance, time, slurm

- I have two jobs:

  - Job A(makespan=45 and job B(makespan=45)
- I have paired both jobs to run together:

  - Jobs A and B paired formed C - C(makespan = 190)

Resources allocated for it:

- Unlimited memory
- Diskspace
- Only using 1 socket and only using one slot in the socket. Therefore, making it 1 core.

Why are the times so different?

What's the best way to calculate the makespan ?

Comment: You should add more information and details about your problem. How are you submitting the jobs? What resources do they need?...

Comment: makespan = time of execution, I am using a batch file to submit the jobs, they do not need specific resources, the only exception is that i am using only 1 socket  @CarlesFenoy